Will a Sprengel pump contaminate the vacuum chamber?
I'm in need of a vacuum pump for a vacuum distillation setup and also to evaporate solvents en vacuo with a high vacuum. I could get an oilless rough pump to get the low vacuum and then use an expensive glass diffusion pump for the high vacuum, but I live with other people and a rough pump of that sort is dreadfully noisy.
So I thought making a glass Sprengel pump* would be much more quiet and unlike the glass diffusion pump I can use it at atmospheric pressure. Since I'm looking for purity in my vacuum chamber, I need to be certain none of the mercury contaminates the vacuum chamber. My question is will a Sprengel pump backstream into the vacuum chamber or contaminate the vacuum chamber with mercury vapor?
* demonstration of a setup and use in conjunction of a Crookes radiometer as an indicator of a pressure between $\approx \pu{1 Pa}$ (or $\pu{0.0075 torr}$) and $\approx \pu{1 mPa}$ (or $\pu{7.5E−7 torr}$, reference), see the video Sprengel Vacuum Pump: The most efficient vacuum pump ever?

At this point in time there is NO good reason to use a mercury pump, particularly in your dwelling with other people around. Mercury has not been used in diffusion pumps for many decades now for good reasons. I suggest at the least that you consider using one of the various low vapor pressure oils that replaced mercury many years ago.

Once you use a mercury pump it will have contaminated everything that is connected to it, and so you will need to throw all that away as you will never get rid of the mercury.  As Jon Custer writes they have not been used for decades because of this.

@OP By the way, i) what are the solvents you want to remove by distillation (and from what mixture), ii) what is the intended scale of operation, iii) what is the (approximate) concentration of these now and what is an acceptable concentration after their removal/the intended use of your compound(s) after that? Beside extraction, the addition of an other solvent to create an azeotrope with a lower boiling point to easier remove a high boiling solvent may be an alternative cheaper/faster installed.  See for instance Wikipedia's compilation here.

@porphyrin Yea (Building A Mercury Still) there are folks with access to quantities of mercury which is is unbelievable (cody's videos with / about mercury). Sometimes to some degree instructive (e.g., Faraday motor) however unthinkable this way today with OSHA in a public school, e.g. in Europe.

The oil-free setup using mercury installs now the vapor pressure of mercury as the limiting lowest pressure at a given operational temperature which is low, but not non-zero:

NISTIR 6643
Gaffney et al. reports a value of $\pu{0.261 Pa}$ ($\pu{2.58E−6 atm}$) at a temperature of $\pu{25 ^\circ{}C}$.
Addition: Around 14 min into the video by Cody lab about the Sprengler pump, the author actually does observe little droplets of condensed mercury inside the Crookes radiometer, on the wall not facing the filament light bulb while the temperature around the setup is $\pu{32 ^\circ{}F}$ (or $\pu{0 ^\circ{}C}$, or $\pu{273 K}$).

Huber, M. L.; Laesecke, A.; Friend, D. G. The Vapor Pressure of Mercury. NISTIR 6643, April 2006, pub_id=50348.
Gaffney, J. S.; Marley, N. A. In-Depth Review of Atmospheric Mercury: Sources, Transformations, and Potential Sinks. EECT 2014, 2, 1–21. https://doi.org/10.2147/EECT.S37038 (open access).
